Sending images from ReactNative Expo to SpringBoot
I'm using expo-image-picker in reactnative and trying to send blob images to the backserver(springboot), but I keep getting the following error.
Everything else is sending fine, it's only the images that are having issues, so it's not a url issue.
And testing with images(ex. image.jpg) in postman succeeded.
console.log(error) just pops up that one.
This is the error in reactnative
[AxiosError: Network Error]
This is my code.
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

export default function DetailRecordScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const { ipnumber, date, user_code } = route.params;
  const [status, requestPermission] = ImagePicker.useMediaLibraryPermissions();
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [id, setId] = useState(0);
  let k = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
  const uploadImage = async () => {
    if (!status?.granted) {
      const permission = await requestPermission();
      if (!permission.granted) {
        Alert.alert(
          "title",
          "content",
          [
            { text: "cancel", style: "cancel" },
            { text: "setting", onPress: () => Linking.openSettings() },
          ]
        );
        return;
      }
    }

    // image upload
    if (images.length < 10) {
      try {
        const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
          allowsEditing: false,
          quality: 0.5,
          allowsMultipleSelection: true,
          selectionLimit: 10 - images.length,
        });

        if (!result.cancelled && result.assets && result.assets.length > 0) {
          const selectedUri = result.assets.map((asset) => asset.uri);

          const newImage = selectedUri.map((uri) => {
            return { id: id + k++, uri: uri };
          });
          setImages(images.concat(newImage));
          setId(id + k);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("..."
    }
  };

  // uri -> blob
  const fetchImageFromUri = async () => {
    const newImage = await Promise.all(
      images.map(async (image) => {
        const response = await fetch(image.uri);
        return await response.blob();
      })
    );

    return newImage;
  };

  const handlePost = async () => {
    try {
      // make formDate
      const postingImages = await fetchImageFromUri();
      const formData = new FormData();
      postingImages.forEach((blob, index) => {
        formData.append("multipartFiles", blob);
      });
      formData.append("user_code", user_code);
      formData.append("date", date);

      console.log("formData ", formData);

      // save image
      await axios.post(`http://${ipnumber}:8080/image/post`, formData);
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (...)
  };

This is the backserver code.
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor    
public class ImageService {
    @Value("${cloud.aws.s3.bucket}")
    private String bucket;
    private final String bucketUrl = "https://define-bucket.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/";

    private final AmazonS3 amazonS3;
    private final ImageMapper imageMapper;

    public List<String> uploadImage(List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles, int user_code, String date) {
        
        List<String> fileKeyList = new ArrayList<>();

        multipartFiles.forEach(file -> {
            String fileName = user_code + "/" + createFileName(file.getOriginalFilename());

            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            metadata.setContentLength(file.getSize());
            metadata.setContentType(file.getContentType());

            try(InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream()) {
                amazonS3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucket, fileName, inputStream, metadata)
                        .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));

                fileKeyList.add(fileName);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "파일 업로드 실패");
            }
        });

        // DB INSERT
        ImageVo imageVo = new ImageVo();
        imageVo.setUser_code(user_code);
        imageVo.setDate(date);
        imageVo.setUrl(fileKeyList);
        imageMapper.insertImageName(imageVo);

        return fileKeyList;
    }

    public List<String> showImage(int user_code, String date) {
        ImageVo imageVo = imageMapper.getImageByUserCodeAndDate(user_code, date);
        List<String> fileKeyList = imageVo != null? imageVo.getUrl() : List.of();

        return fileKeyList.stream().map(fileKey -> bucketUrl + fileKey).toList();
    }

    public ImageVo getImageByPeriod(int user_code, String start, String end) {
        return imageMapper.getImageByPeriod(user_code, start, end);
    }

    public void deleteImage(int user_code, String date) {

        ImageVo imageVo = imageMapper.getImageByUserCodeAndDate(user_code, date);
        List<String> fileKeyList = imageVo.getUrl();
        //List<String> imageUrls = imageVo.getUrl();

        if (fileKeyList != null) {
            fileKeyList.forEach(fileKey -> {
                try {
                    amazonS3.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(bucket, fileKey));
                    System.out.println("Deleted file: " + fileKey);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Error deleting file: " + fileKey + " - " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }

        // DB DELETE
        imageMapper.deleteImageName(user_code, date);
    }
    

    private String createFileName(String originalFileName) {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() + "_" + originalFileName;
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/daily")
public class DailyController {
    private final DailyService dailyService;

    @Autowired
    public DailyController(DailyService dailyService) {
        this.dailyService = dailyService;
    }

    // POST
    @PostMapping("/post")
    public void insertDaily(@RequestBody DailyVo dailyVo) {
        dailyService.insertDaily(dailyVo);
    }

    // GET
    @GetMapping("/records/{user_code}/{date}")
    public DailyVo showDaily(@PathVariable int user_code, @PathVariable String date) {
        return dailyService.getDailyByUserCodeAndDate(user_code, date);
    }

    @GetMapping("/records/{user_code}")
    public List<DailyVo> showDailyByUserCode(@PathVariable int user_code) {
        return dailyService.getDailyByUserCode(user_code);
    }

    @GetMapping("/state/{user_code}/{month}")
    public List<Map<String, Object>> showDailyByUserCode(@PathVariable int user_code, @PathVariable String month) {
        return dailyService.getStateByUserCodeAndMonth(user_code, month);
    }

    @GetMapping("/period")
    public List<DailyVo> peroidDaily(@RequestBody periodRequestDto periodDto) {
        return dailyService.getDailyByPeriod(periodDto.getUser_code(), periodDto.getStart(), periodDto.getEnd());
    }

    // UPDATE
    @PutMapping("/records/edit")
    public void updateDaily(@RequestBody DailyVo dailyVo) {
        dailyService.updateDaily(dailyVo);
    }

    // DELETE
    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{user_code}/{date}")
    public void deleteDaily(@PathVariable int user_code, @PathVariable String date) {
        dailyService.deleteDaily(user_code, date);
    }

}

Probably the information is going to the back server correctly. This is the backserver log.
[Nothing to write: null body]
I want to know which part is the problem.
Thanks for reading!

Have you tried to set Content-Type to multipart/form-data when sending FormData?
